# Benchmarks for optimised Math Libraries across platforms

Tags: software, computational-chemistry, high-performance-computing, computational-frameworks

Are there any benchmarks of low-level and high-level math operations from different Math libraries on corresponding architectures?

Here are a few packages:

- LAPACK / BLAS  + ATLAS ([stock version from netlib](https://www.netlib.org/))
- [OpenBLAS](https://www.openblas.net/)
- [Intel MKL](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/oneapi-programming-guide/top/api-based-programming/intel-oneapi-math-kernel-library-onemkl.html)
- ACML (AMD core math library)
- [Apple Accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/accelerate/)

Comment: Please feel free to add any other math library as well as different architectures for existing libraries.

Comment: Do you mean performance data for these libraries on particular machines, or do you mean benchmark calculations that you can download and run yourself?

Comment: Either would do, actually. I just wanted to get an idea about different scenarios. It would be a lot of work, but I am happy to try benchmarking them on our hardware.